# Fix Sorting for API-JSON Values

Tags: bug, status-declined, api, sorting, json

If I want to see my 5 most recent answers in HTML, I can do so by visiting:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/useranswers.html?userid=130154&page=1&pagesize=5&sort=newest

If I want to see my five most recent answers in JSON, I would likely visit:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/useranswers.json?userid=130154&page=1&pagesize=5&sort=newest

Unfortunately, the JSON option doesn't respect the &sort value. Instead it shows the first five answers, rather than the last 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not officially support the /api until we announce we're working on it.

All requests of this nature will be declined.

Also, fair warning: since the api is unannounced, it may be changed at any time with no announcements.

Comment: No problem. Appreciate the input :)